# Sporadic problem making a directory in ntfs external drive

Tags: ntfs, external-hdd, cp, mkdir

I have an NTFS formatted external drive that I use to back up my home directory and another directory called /virt which I use to store the files for a virtual box.
Using rsync, I regularely back up both of these directories to the external drive, no problmes there.
I make backups of the home directory using

```
cp -alv "/media/external/home" "/media/external/`date +home_%y%m%d`"
```

This seems to also work, however if I try

```
cp -alv "media/external/virt" "/media/external/`date +virt_%y%m%d`"
```

I get the error:

```
cp: cannot create directory `/media/external/virt_141106': No such file or directory
```

Note that I still have plenty of space for this operation on the external drive.
Also interesting, if I try to make a directory in this folder

```
cd /media/external
mkdir test
mkdir: cannot create directory `test': No such file or directory
```

I can make a directory called "test", at least some of the time, if I unmount and remount the drive and then try to make that directory again.

Does anyone have any idea why I am getting this strange behaviour and what I can do about it?

Answer (score 1):

I think that ntfs is just generally bad for hard links. I converted to an ext4 file system for backups and things are working a lot nicer now.